# How to prove that the lower level set of a continuous function as a correspondence is continuous?

Tags: producer-theory

"If $s(•)$ is a continuous function, and $A(a):=\{x:s(x)\leq a\}$ is its lower contour set at $a$, then $A(•)$ is a continuous correspondence."

I can't find the right way to prove the upper hemi and lower hemi continuous of $A(•)$

(And is there a specific name of this $A(•)$? Such as "lower contour correspondence" or something? I've tried to search something like this but get nothing.)

Comment: Let's call $X$ the set of all possible $x$ $(x\in X)$. From the definition of $A(a)$, it is clear that $A:s(X)\to \mathcal{P}(x)$, so it seems that if we admit non-conected sets, then $A(a)$ is a well defined function. If we do not admit non-conected sets, then $A(a)$ IS a correspondence.

Comment: What definitions of upper and lower hemicontinuity are you using?